# Xcode: Adding transition animation on UITabBar

Tags: xcode4, uitabbarcontroller

Can we add transition animation on UITabBar when clicking on tab bar item?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The similar kind of problem has been solved here:

http://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/animated-transition-between-tabbars-view-on-iphone/

Comment: their solution is working but there's problem when the same tab is re-clicked it will animate over it self, how can animate the view in front of a white background? I hope I was clear :)